# What is the relation between cipher suite and certificate?

Tags: certificates, rsa, ecc, ciphers

I generated my self signed certificate using openssl and I chose ECC keys (prime 256v1) for root certificate but while authenticating with the server i.e. IBM cloud and my device the negotiated cipher suite was TLS-ECDHE-RSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256 so now I'm confused because I've generated ECC keys but RSA has been used in cipher suites what I thought was it will be TLS-ECDHE-ECDSA-WITH-AES-128-GCM-SHA256 .

So is there any interdependency between cipher suite and certificate used for authentication or they are both independently working without any relation?

Comment: Did you 'generate my ... cert' for the _client_ or the _server_? The _server_ cert matches the ciphersuite in protocols through TLS1.2 (but no longer in 1.3); the _client_ cert does not.

Comment: Im generating client certificate as well as root certificate.  Root certificate I added to the cloud IBM

Comment: Then, as I said: client cert and ciphersuite aren't matched. More specifically, the client cert can use any of the algorithms specified by the server in the CertRequest message, regardless of the ciphersuite.